# Replace in place a string in file with text from 2nd file

Tags: awk

I have two files as follows

config:

```
which [box-address]
  Command ssh user[box2-address]
```

address:

```
192.168.0.10
```

I want to replace in place the `[box-address]` in "config" with the contents from "address"

I am able to insert the content but overwrite the entire config file each time so instead of

```
which 192.168.0.10
  Command ssh user 192.168.0.20
```

I end up with

```
192.168.0.10
```

as the only thing in the file

What am I doing wrong

```
awk '/\[box-address\]/{system("cat config");next}1' address > config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing `address`, not `config`, as the input to `awk`. It will never match `/\[box-address\]/`. Your command is effectively just overwriting `config` with the content of `address`.

The following approach should meet your requirements, it reads the content of `address` into a variable in the `BEGIN` block and then replaces any instances of `[box-address]` with it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline l < "address"}/\[box-address\]/{gsub(/\[box-address\]/,l)}1' config
```

Result:

```
which 192.168.0.10
  Command ssh user[box2-address]
```

Comment: HI thanks! This does indeed provide the correct output to screen however it is not saving the changes to the config file...

Comment: added  > temp && mv temp config to the end and works....learned that earlier today frm FcknGioconda